# Получение нестатических переменных с другого класса без экземпляра класса

Tags: java, swing

Привет. Есть класс с конструктором, который инициализирует компоненты Swing, а также слушателей (присутствует много методов, использующих интернет-запросы. Как мне получить определенные нестатические переменные из этого класса без экземпляра класса, потому что, если создавать новый экземпляр, будут выполняться методы с интернет-запросами и нагружать систему. 
Если добавить пустой конструктор, то я все равно же не смогу управлять переменными именно уже созданного класса. 
Есть какое-нибудь решение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не-не, вы хотите что-то не то.

Вы никак не можете получить нестатические переменные без экземпляра класса, потому что они существуют только в экземпляре класса.

Вам вряд ли хочется создавать новый экземпляр класса для чтения из него переменных, это скорее всего лишено смысла. Думаю, вам нужно раздобыть ссылку на *нужный* существующий экземпляр класса, и пользоваться ею.

Comment: Понял, благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша задача хорошо ложится на паттерн одиночка. Сам класс будет хранить ссылку на свой объект (в статической переменной), и вы уже можете получить эту ссылку из любого места, где "виден" данный класс. А там уже через ссылку вызвать гетеры для получения нужных вам данных.
Плюс одиночки в том, что объект класса будет создан всего один раз, все последующие разы будет только возвращаться ссылка на него, что собственно, вам и нужно.